# How to recursively explore python nested dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

I'm curious if there is a way to recursively explore nested dictionaries in python. By this I mean, say we have an example such as the below:

```py
d = {'a':{'b':{'c':[1,2,3]}}}
```

What code would be necessary to get the contents of the innermost dictionary `{'c':[1,2,3]}`, traversing through `a` and `b`? In this case, it's not too much effort to write `d['a']['b']['c']` but what if there was an arbitrarily large number of nested dictionaries, such that this was impossible/overly cumbersome.

My gut instinct is that I would need to create a general tree class with key and payload attributes, parsing the dictionary and storing it in my object, which I could design to be parsed using DFS, BFS, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive approach. The idea is to check if the current's dictionary value is an instance of a `dict`, if it is call the same function with the `values` as input, otherwise return the dictionary:

```
def get_inner_dict(d):
    for _, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            return get_inner_dict(v) 
        else:
            return d
```

---

```
get_inner_dict(d)
# {'c': [1, 2, 3]}
```